# Types of functions returning functions in OCaml and how they are displayed

Tags: ocaml

I am studying for a test, and one of the practice problems is to write a function of the type `(int->int)->(int->int)`. The provided answer

```
fun x y -> (x 1) + y
```

But when I put something like

```
let funct x y = (x 1) + y;;
```

it spits out (int->int)->int->int. Is this any different from the version with the extra parentheses. If yes how, if no why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No different, `->` is right-associative. Same reason why `(1 - 2) - (3 - 4)` is same as `1 - 2 - (3 - 4)` (subtraction being left-associative, the effect is mirrored).

This hinges on the existence of currying in OCaml, i.e. the fact that a function of one parameter that returns a function of one parameter is indistinguishable from function of two parameters - i.e. `f 1 2` is same as `(f 1) 2`.

Comment: That is a huge help. Thank you very much.